# Wrong figure number at \ref

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm writing a tex where I have several figures at my chapter 3, I guess it is 27 figures.

after my section 3.3
my `(figure \ref{fig:.......})` are giving me the wrong figure.
when it should be giving me
figure 3.19
it is giving me figure 3.3 or 3.4 in every figure after section 3.3 the references are wrong.

here is part of my section 3.3, the first figure here should be the number 3.19, and the `\ref` is returning 3.3

```
\section{Arquivo Digital Log Interchange Standard File (Extensão Dlis)}
\label{sec:extensaodlis}

Os arquivos no formato Dlis, podem ser importados a partir do menu 
\textbf{Projeto} – \textbf{Importar} – \textbf{Arquivos Dlis}. É necessário que 
o usuário defina alguns parâmetros durante a importação deste tipo de arquivo 
(figura \ref{fig:importacaodoarquivodlis}). Nesta primeira etapa de importação, 
você poderá associar o conteúdo importado de cada arquivo selecionado a um poço 
existente no projeto, ou definir um novo nome (resultando da criação de um novo 
arquivo). Na importação de apenas um arquivo, é mostrado na caixa de texto 
acima da área onde o conteúdo do arquivo o caminho de acesso do arquivo 
importado, mas caso tenha selecionado muitos arquivos este caminho não será 
mostrado e sim apenas a relação de nomes de poços (figura 
\ref{fig:importacaodoarquivodlis} , seta azul). 

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{\importacaodedados importacaodoarquivodlis.png}
\label{fig:importacaodoarquivodlis}
\caption{Importação de Arquivo Dlis.}
\end{figure}


Na seguinte tela, serão apresentadas as informações contidas no arquivo 
Dlis, Na caixa “\textbf{grupos de curvas encontrados}”, você visualizará o nome 
do arquivo (poço), e se houverem arquivos “Frames” que correspondem a grupos de 
curvas estes serão importados para o projeto Trace. Na tabela abaixo é possível 
alterar o nome e a unidade de todas as curvas, além de associar à semântica 
(figura \ref{fig:arquivodlis}). Você poderá decidir importar 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{\importacaodedados documentarrowicon.png} ou não 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{\importacaodedados documenterroricon.png} uma curva 
apenas clicando sobre ela. Caso a curva selecionada represente o índice, o 
programa lhe enviará uma mensagem sobre o estado da curva selecionada (figuras 
\ref{fig:importarrenomearassociarsemanticaacurva} e 
\ref{fig:curvadeindiceaserimportada}).

Assim como no importador de arquivos texto (ver item 
\ref{sec:dadosprolab}), você tem a opção de visualizar apenas as semânticas 
compatíveis às contidas nos dados, ou associar a unidade padrão da semântica 
quando a curva não possuir unidades definidas. Você tem a opção de deixar que o 
sistema sobrescreva os atributos dos poços, com valores encontrados no arquivo, 
selecionando a check box na parte inferior a direita do ajudante de importação. 
E se algum mapeamento estiver selecionado, curvas associadas a semântica 
litologia serão automaticamente mapeadas durante a importação, ou seja, será 
criada uma curva de litologia. Ao clicar sobre a combo box localizada na parte 
inferior do ajudante de importação, chamada \textbf{mapeamento de litologias} 
você terá acesso ao mapeamento default (padrão PETROBRAS) existente no 
programa, ou outro existente. Após todas as definições realizadas clique em 
concluir. 



\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{\importacaodedados arquivodlis.png}
\label{fig:arquivodlis}
\caption{Arquivo Dlis.}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to put the `label` *after* the `caption`, not before it.  The following typesets *Compare figures 1 and 3*:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{One} \label{sec:one}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\label{fig:another}\caption{Another figure} % Wrong!
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Yet another figure}\label{fig:yetanother} % Right.
\end{figure}

Compare figures~\ref{fig:another} and \ref{fig:yetanother}.

\end{document}
```